# How to remove a border from a UIButtonBarItem in an iPad navigation bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

After creating a standard/default navigation style application, I am trying to add a reload button to a navigation bar to its "RootViewController". The following works, however adds a border to the button, which is as far as I can tell fairly non standard for iPad apps.

How do I add a button that does not have a border?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    if (reloadButton == nil) {
        reloadButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:  UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target: nil action: nil];
        reloadButton.style =  UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;
        reloadButton.target = self;
        reloadButton.action = @selector(reloadRates);
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = reloadButton;
    } 
    ....
}
```

Ultimately this app targets both iPhone and iPad, but I am only concerned about iPad for now.

It turns out that changing the style from `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain` to  `UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered` result in the same bordered button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the iOS Human Interface Guidelines:

> Plain style—For example, the Compose
>   button in the Mail toolbar uses plain
>   style. This style is suitable for
>   toolbars only. In fact, if you specify
>   the plain style for a button in the
>   navigation bar, it is converted to the
>   bordered style.

Most iPad apps you are seeing use a split view which has a UIToolbar at the top.

Answer (score 11):

In XCode 4.5.2 just set the BackgroundImage of the Button to an empty Image:
(buttonSetup is type of UIBarButtonItem)

```
[self.buttonSetup setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Amazing! I've been searching for this for a long time. Thank you. :)